# Forma correcta de enviar datos a una vista con jpa spring framework

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, vaadin

Cual es la mejor practica para enviar datos a una vista con `Spring` framework, es correcto enviar un entity a una vista o primero convertir un entity a un dto.

Esto por el tema de seguridad, que no todos los datos de un tabla son necesarios enviar a la vista.

Ejemplo: Entity Vacante

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private User idUsuario;
@Basic(optional = false)
```

Entity Usuario:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
```

y en la vista simplemente traer los datos asi:

`Vacante.getId();`

`Vacante.getIdUsuario().getNombre();`

O crear un dto con los datos que solo quiero traer a la vista y PASAR LOS DATOS DEL ENTITY AL DTO Y enviar este dto a la vista y no el entity.

Como dato adicional estoy usando `Vaadin`.

Comment: siempre será mejor usar un DTO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nunca conectes una entidad directamente a una vista, es una mala práctica por muchos motivos. Para empezar, una entidad es un objeto de tu dominio con persistencia y al utilizarlo nunca sabes cuando vas a estar abriendo conexiones a la base de datos que no quieres abrir (no es un problema tanto de seguridad sino de rendimiento).

Obviando lo anterior, hay un motivo más importante de por qué debes usar DTO's. A lo mejor en este momento todos los datos que necesitas en la vista están en la entidad pero puede ocurrir que en el futuro tus requisitos cambien y tengas que añadir un campo nuevo que no está en base de datos, si tuvieras un dto pues añades el campo nuevo y listo. En una entidad jamás es una buena práctica añadir un campo que no corresponda con una columna de base de datos...

Más motivos, si vas a crear una api y quieres documentarla (usando swagger por ejemplo), lo normal es conectar tu dto de salida a swagger para que te muestre tus datos de salida en la documentación de la api, con un dto puedes controlar los campos que muestras, si tuvieras una entidad no y estarías mostrando todo lo que contiene tu base de datos (mala práctica de nuevo)...

Si conectas las entidades a la vista, el programa probablemente funcionará pero cuando te des cuenta de estos problemas o te surjan otros y tengas que cambiar todas tus vistas va a ser muy complicado...

Comment: Gracias me sirvió y me diste mas visibilidad al tema.

Answer (score 1):

Estás en SpringMVC, por lo que lo ideal sería tener una clase controladora la cual se encarga de dar soporte a la vista.

**Por experiencia y buscando tener el codigo lo más modular y mantenible posible, este tipo de arquitectura te será muy útil en un futuro, dándote un nivel de muy bueno de alta cohesión y bajo Acoplamiento.**

La clase controladora hará uso de los servicios que necesites, por ejemplo Servicio usuario y Servicio vacante y son estos servicios los que harán uso de los DTO (usuarioDTO) creandolos cuando se invoca al DAO de la entidad correspondiente y este le devuelve la información de dicha entidad.

Esta estructura adicional te da la posibilidad de invocar a varios DAOs que necesitas para dar soporte a las solicitudes de la vista. Como ves tu clase controladora no tiene conocimiento alguno de los DAOs o entidades de negocio, se limita a llamar a los servicios para que estos le proporcionen la información necesaria.

Luego estaría la capa DAO que es la que se encarga de gestionar las entidades con tu BBDD.

Por último estarían las entidades.

> Quedando tu código dividido en las siguientes capas:
>
> Controlador
>
> Servicios - Servicios.DTOs
>
> DAO
>
> Entities

Y si, la idea es utilizar DTOs por temas de rendimiento y por todos los aspectos que ha mencionado @Blazerg.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de dtos solo hace más complejo el código.  La idea es que puedas utilizar las entidades para transferir la información entre capas.  En caso de que tu aplicación utilice una capa de integración como servicio web o rest si es conveniente utilizar un objeto de transferencia de datos.  En Spring MVC las entidades se evalúan en el servidor así que lo que no usas no se expone al cliente.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió.